# The definition of sequence spaces in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading Kreyszig's Introduction to Functional Analysis. On page seven, the text provides its first example of a metric space that isn't a Euclidean Space:

[image: Example of a sequence space]

I want to clarify what the following represents:

[image: Defining a sequence in a sequence space]

I think what this is saying is that, every sequence $x$ in our space consists of complex numbers, all of which are no farther apart than some real number $c_x$ ( which itself may or may not be a function of $x$ ).

Is that correct?

Comment: Or maybe its, "Every sequence $x$ in our space consists of complex numbers, all of which are no farther [ from zero ] than some real number $c_x$ ( which itself may or may not be a function of $x$ ).

Comment: The latter. In English we ordinarily say that each sequence $x$ is *bounded*.

Comment: Thank you! So, our set $\mathbb{X}$ is a set of complex numbers inside a circle of radius $c_x$?

Comment: Yes. Are you sure you have completed the prerequisites for such a course?

Comment: I'm sure I have not. But--that's life.

Comment: What it means is that $x=(e_j)_j\in l^{\infty}$ iff $\sup_j|e_j|<\infty.$ That is,  the members of $l^{\infty}$ are the bounded sequences of complex numbers.